# How can i select elements from an IEnumerable to store them in another IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, wpf, ienumerable

I have built a custom User Control, that has as input an IEnumerable, and it should return also an IEnumerable. This is to have a flexible control that can receive any collection of objects. Here is some code snippets to help you understand my problem:

- Item Source

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MultiSelectionComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(
  new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

  public IEnumerable ItemsSource
  {
      get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
  }
  ```
- Selected Items

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MultiSelectionComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
  new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectionComboBox.OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

  public IEnumerable SelectedItems
  {
      get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
      set
      {
          SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
      }
  }
  ```

I was able to have my control work except for this part that Build the SelectedItems property

```
foreach(string s in appo)
{
  IEnumerator en = ItemsSource.GetEnumerator();
  while (en.MoveNext())
  {
      var val = en.Current;
      Type type = val.GetType();
      PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(DisplayMemberPath);
      if (property != null)
      {
          string name = (string)property.GetValue(val, null);
          if(name == s)
          {
              // need something here          
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Basically inside the `if` i have checked that the current element of the `IEnumerator`en must be included in the SelectedItem. The problem is that i don't know how i can include this element in the output (that is SelectedItems).

I am open also to different approach, if you have better ideas

Comment: If you want to be able to add elements to an existing SelectedItems collection (instead of creating a new one), change its type to ICollection, which has Add, Remove and Clear methods.

Comment: @Clemens ICollection isn't an interface? this would require to actually choose a collection (like List or ObservableCollection) as type for my SelectedItemsProperty

Comment: Don't use that GetEnumerator thing; use `foreach (var val in ItemsSource) {`.

Comment: It's an interface directly derived from IEnumerable, with the additional contract to add or remove elements.

Comment: ICollection is an interface.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you, i'll do it

Comment: @DanieleSartori Who provides the collection in SelectedItems? If you make the type `IList`, that enforces a requirement that they have to provide something that implements all the methods and properties in `IList` -- including `Add()`. In effect, you're insisting that they give you some kind of collection class that allows you to add items to it.

Comment: @Clemens if i declare my SelectedItems as ICollection, it doesn't show Add. Only Count is available

Comment: @DanieleSartori Try `IList` instead.

Comment: IList has them all

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the generic `ICollection<T>`. Use it as `ICollection<object>`.

Comment: By the way @DanieleSartori , when you say "generic IEnumerable", you seem to be talking about *non-generic* System.Collections.IEnumerable -- is that correct? The generic one is `IEnumerable<T>`. "Generic" is precisely what the one you're using is not, by the C# meaning of the term "generic".

Comment: @EdPlunkett i didn't know how to spell it right. When i was looking for a solution, i always find an implementation of IEnumerable, not the IEnuberable itself. So yes i'm referring to non-generic System.Collections.IEnumerable. Btw i'm testing your solution in the meantime

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion. I finally made it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `IEnumerable` does not have the ability to add items. You therefore need to change it to be something that has an Add method, `IList` for example, or `ICollection<object>`.